Looking for an explanation of how "case of" works inside a record in Delphi
I'm currently an intern at a company that's in the process of converting their internal programs from Delphi to C#, using Delphi2C#.
I don't know any Delphi and my knowledge of C# is also very limited.
I came across a record that is reading from a .DIR file, created by another internal program.
The .DIR file appears to be in unicode and I can't find a way to open it other than with notepad, but that information doesn't tell me much.
The Delphi record looks something like this
myrecord = record
   case smallint of
       1: (a : smallint);
       2: (b :char;
           c :smallint);
       3: (d :smallint;
           e: char;
           f: smallint);
         etc etc...
end;

Delphi2C# turned the record into a struct, and while trying to read from the file, I do get values into the struct, but the values are all wrong.
So what I'm wondering is, what sets the conditions for the case statement? Is that information within the .DIR file or am I missing something?
I'm sorry if my question is incomplete or doesn't make sense in this context, I'm fairly new at programming and this is my first post here.

This is a record with a variant part. This language feature is fully documented in the official language documentation.

Variant Records in Delphi correspond to Unions in C(++), and (I assume) C#. For each variant part (1/2/3) the data starts at the same address, so "a", "b" and "d" are at the same address, and "c" and "e" are at the same address (assuming packed record and unicode character, ie. 2 bytes char).

Just a heads-up. I don't know that tool but I know C# and I've seen my fair share of delphi. I don't see any tool that does more or less 1:1 translation work out well for a complete software. Especially without major revamp post conversion. That being said: maybe also consider a wider context than the acute problem and think about if you can avoid it in the first place. Of course, that is hard to do if you don't know how things are done usually in C#.

@HeartWare there are no(t yet) unions in C#.

@Fildor: Thank you - that's why I said "I assume" because I wasn't sure. Nice to have it (negatively) confirmed.

Yep, unions are still "in the making" but heavily requested. Unfortunately, for OP that means that part probably cannot be translated that easily. Hence my suggestion to take a step back. I am guessing in C# you wouldn't even want to have those "DIR-Files".

Btw once more I wonder what a company is thinking when tasking an intern with something like this. Feels like someone wants this to fail so they can report a "nope. Doesn't work. Need to stick with delphi." ...

@Fildor I understand what you are saying, but they are currently reworking alot of other programs. The goal for me right now is not to complete this conversion during my internship but rather to learn while doing as much as I possibly can. There is a huge possibility that they will scrap all of my code once I'm out of here and start fresh.
You are also 100% right in that we do not want the .DIR files, but I do however want the data in them...

@heartWare so for example b and c reads the same data(or bytes?) in the file even though they are expected to have different types of data?

Ok. I see. So here is a piece of advice from experience regarding lang-to-lang translations in general and delphi to C# specifically: 1:1 rarely works. Extract the requirements, inputs and outputs from the source, then implement it in the target as is canonical for the target. Sometimes you need to move boundaries, too.

" so for example b and c reads the same data(or bytes?" - no. Think of it as "input can be of form 1, 2 or 3. If it is 1, then we have a. If it is 2, then we have b followed by c. ..."

@heartWare it appears that I was wrong in assuming it was in unicode, it appears to be ASCII, is it still 2 bytes per char?

Char size depends on the Delphi version.  From Delphi 2009 that means two bytes per character, and before it was single byte per character.  If you are doing any translation Delphi Language Guide is your best staring point. The layout of the record will also depend on whether record is packed or not and which alignment is used, which will be either default one or controlled with compiler directives.

Don't you have access to the source of that 'another internal program' so that you can see how the Delphi code writes to the .dir file?

Don't open the .dir file with Notepad, use a hex editor so that you can look at the actual data instead of the way Notepad interprets it

^^ having the producing code might also help in understanding if those files are actually needed at all or if you could just put it all in one .net assembly.

@janDoggen at the moment no, we do have access to the source code of that other internal program, but the version we have is rather broken and written in C++. The only thing I can tell from it is that it seems to write in bytes of 6.
Huge thank you for recommending a hex editor, my brain is still a question mark at this point, but atleast now I have some insight to the structure of the file!

Once you're ready to move beyond Notepad and hex editors, you may want start formalizing the parsing (or "importing") with a BinaryReader. But you need to confirm how and where used, if any! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=net-8.0
